# How to solve "Notice: Undefined index: name" while inserting form entries in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

Following is the code that inserts the form entries into the database.
`include.php` file is for database connectivity

```
<?php
require "../includes/include.php";
$name=$_POST['name'];
if($name="")
    echo "Name field can't be empty !!!<br>";
$faculty=$_POST['faculty'];
if($faculty="")
    echo "Please select your faculty !!!<br>";
$rating=$_POST['rating'];
if($rating="")
    echo "Please select the respective rating !!!<br>";
$response=$_POST['response'];

$name=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $name);
$faculty=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $faculty);
$rating=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $rating);
$response=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $response);
$insert_query="insert into feedback(name, faculty, rating, response) values ('$name', '$faculty', '$rating', '$response')";
$query_result=mysqli_query($con, $insert_query);
?>
```

It shows the error while inserting values

> Notice: Undefined index: name in /var/www/html/Mini_Project/php/feedback_script.php on line 12
> .

Can someone please help with what exactly has gone wrong?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` gives you what?

Comment: Please make sure  your form where you post your value has an input which has `name='name'`

Comment: also, your query is open to SQL injection, mysqli_real_escape_string() function is not enough to prevent people with malicious intent, please use prepared statement for better security.

Answer (score 1):

Your assignment of `$name`, `$faculty`, `$rating`, and `$response` expects your `$_POST` array to have certain keys in it. If you cannot garantee your `$_POST` to have all that, it's best to use the [null coalesce operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) (i.e. double question mark `??`) to define a fallback value for assignment:

```php
$name=$_POST['name'] ?? "";
if($name="")
    echo "Name field can't be empty !!!<br>";
$faculty=$_POST['faculty'] ?? "";
if($faculty="")
    echo "Please select your faculty !!!<br>";
$rating=$_POST['rating'] ?? "";
if($rating="")
    echo "Please select the respective rating !!!<br>";
$response=$_POST['response'] ?? "";
```